# Mark question state on the user's answers listing

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow

**Feature request:** Is there an easy way to visually mark an entry on the user's page's answer listing for the case when a question has been accepted/closed but not for the user at hand?

I usually revisit some of my answers to questions to check whether I could improve it further to achieve the accepted state, but the a question has already an accepted (and probably superior) answer other than mine.

I guess, this would require `+N` (where `N >= 0`) query for the user page and will be declined.

(To the performance enthusiasts: compare the load caused by this additional query with the load of opening K questions in a quick succession :)

**Edit:** To avoid confusion I'm referring to this listing:
[image: Current listing stlye]

An *example* for my proposal:
[image]

Comment: +1: I've also wished for this, partly for my own curiosity and partly so I can improve my answers to "pending" questions.

Comment: I joined the do-it-yourself club :)

Comment: I was just about to request this same thing when I found at least two other dupes.

Comment: This would be a great addition - I know I would look at Questions where my Answer was not the Accepted one to see the final solution. Self-education and correction by looking at the answers after the quiz.

Comment: I was about to suggest this. It would be a great feature!

Comment: I was also about to suggest this. There are many reasons to see this (and it doesn't hurt anyone to show it). For me since I stay within one discipline it certainly gives me a good sense of who is asking answer-able questions and also who might be asking questions but having standards that are way-too-high in terms of expectations of the answers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To answer Marc's question about who this change would help:

In the first instance it helps everybody as it could lead to improved answers.

It helps the OP for the same reason. Unless the OP has abandoned the question (or the site) they must feel that none of the existing answers fully solve their problem, so having answers improved should help.

Finally it "helps" the answerer in that their improved answer gains more up-votes, they gain more rep.

Comment: very true and nice. +1

Answer (score 2):

I can't see why it would need that much extra load; I don't know how the db is constructed, but I would *expect* this to be about the same as getting the total number of answers (already shown). Plus the "I have an accepted flag" could always be stored on the question row (if it isn't already).

But! Who does it help? People getting answers to questions? Or just us addicts trying to see how old answers are doing?

Personally (if it was my change budget), I'd rather see more investment in getting the site perfect for the people with questions, new users, that sort of thing.

Comment: Does this mean it's [status-declined] or something you're still thinking about 2 and a half years later?

Comment: @animuson when I posted this answer, I was not associated with SE as a developer; any views expressed here are simply those of me as a site user

Comment: In fact the query that retrieves the list of my answers already includes `AcceptedAnswerId` via a join to questions, which is how the code knows to paint the box green when _this_ answer is the _accepted_ answer. It should be exactly zero additional load to know that the accepted answer is null or, if not null, that it is an answer that is _not_ this answer. (This helps for the "accepted an answer from another user" case but, sadly, not for the "question is closed" case (`ClosedDate` is not currently returned by the query, but could be at almost zero additional cost)).