# Answers viewed via a user page should show if the question has an accepted answer

Tags: feature-request, questions, answers, user-interface

When viewing a user's profile, you can see what answers they have added to questions as well as which of their answers were accepted.

It would be nice, however, to have a way to see if a question has an accepted answer that isn't yours. Perhaps a small icon or change in border that states:

> This question has an accepted answer ... but it wasn't yours.

It would help me to know just how many people are being lazy and not accepting answers, as well as how many people have just decided not to listen to my moronic ramblings.

Comment: I am certain this is a duplicate, but the "Related" bar isn't helpful at all.

Comment: Practically dupe of mine: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5053/mark-question-state-on-the-users-answers-listing

Comment: +1 for reminding me to implement this too.

Comment: Yes, that's the one I was thinking of.

Answer (score 1):

This should not matter.

If your answer is NOT good enough, then you should improve it until it is.

Comment: If you disagree with me, I'd like to know why. Perhaps you could convince me.

Comment: I didn't downvote you.

Comment: Thanks :) But you can if you disagree with me, as long as you tell me why.

Comment: Don't upvote what you don't agree with EvilChookie. You'll skew my score :p

Comment: But you're implying that it's a problem with *those people* which is similar to blaming the computer when your code doesn't work right. The fact is, there are bugs in computers and perfectly written code will fail for no (discernable) reason. However, that SHOULD NOT BE YOUR ASSUMPTION. If my answer hasn't been upvoted, or hasn't been accepted, I'm going to continue trying to improve it if I have stuff to add. 
My answers are complete when **I** feel they are complete. The status of the question shouldn't matter.

Comment: I'm not saying the problem is with those people. I'm saying the problem is that I can't see at a glance who has accepted someone else's answer, and who just hasn't accepted an answer at all. I'm not sure I understand where the confusion is on this issue? Seems pretty straight forward to me.

Comment: We are in agreement about the current state of affairs. I, however, do not believe we should change it.

Comment: Status of the question does matter.  Sure, I want to improve my answers so that mine is accepted.  Just as importantly, though, is seeing what the answer was, when mine wasn't the right one.  That way I can learn from other people's answers too.  If my answer wasn't accepted, but another one was, then I want to see that.

My answer is complete only when it asnswers the question/solves the problem posed.  The answer does not live without the question, grasshopper :)

Answer (score 1):

It would help to filter out those answers that does not need to improved, because someone else has provided an accepted answer, and focus on your answers that can be improved to solve the problem that is not yet solved.