# Indicate questions in my profile with accepted answers by others

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, accepted-answer

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Mark question state on the user's answers listing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5053/mark-question-state-on-the-users-answers-listing)
>   [Notification when someone else's answer is accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62600/)
>   [Please show us when we lose an accepted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1659/)
>   [Show other accepted answers in Recent Activity](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30363/)
>   [Answers viewed via a user page should show if the question has an accepted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12250/)

When I answer a question in SO, I check my Answered-list once in a while to see if my answer is accepted, but I can't see if any answer is accepted. This seems like an interesting feature to me.

Sometimes I tend to pick up old questions that haven't been accepted yet, but now I have to check them all. So as a request:

> Is it possible to make questions that are accepted with someone else his answer a color as well? So that we can see which answers are closed and which ones should be picked up again.

The current situation is like this ([1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYqlh.png)), but I am certain that some of these questions are already accepted by the user.

[image: snippet from my own answer view]

Comment: Duplicate of [Notification when someone else's answer is accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62600/), [Please show us when we lose an accepted answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1659/), [Show other accepted answers in Recent Activity](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30363/), [Answers viewed via a user page should show if the question has an accepted answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12250/) [Mark question state on the user's answers listing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5053/), and probably a few others, as well.