# Is it possible to improve the 'Answers' section of our profile pages?

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mark question state on the user's answers listing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5053/mark-question-state-on-the-users-answers-listing)

After using Stackoverflow.com for a few months, I found myself thinking it would be a good idea to improve the 'Answers' section of our profile pages.

As of now, all questions we answer are either green or white indicating that the user selected our answer, or the question is still open, respectively. The improvement I would like to suggest is to introduce a third color (possibly yellow?) to indicate that the user selected an answer, but it wasn't our answer.

IMO this feature would make it so we wouldn't have to click into every question we answered just to see if an answer had been selected yet, which would reduce the requests to Stackoverflow.com servers.

Thanks.

Comment: I disagree with the 'yellow' bit, but the idea seems fine.

Comment: This has been proposed before. I'll see if I can find it.

Comment: I think [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86064/indicate-questions-in-my-profile-with-accepted-answers-by-others) is the one I saw, and its been closed as a duplicate of 5 others.

Comment: Interesting. Seems like they should add the feature then ;)

Comment: @DigitalPrecision This is not a comment on your idea at all... but the number of times something has been posted before should *never* have *anything* to do with the perceived value of that thing.